# How do I pass a char to an executeable from the terminal?

Tags: c, windows, batch-file, winapi

Right now my executable looks like this:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return (argc > 1 ? (GetKeyState(*argv[1]) & 0x8000) : 0);
}
```

and my batch script program looks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

:LOOP
    PING 127.0.0.1 -n 2 >NUL 2>&1 || PING ::1 -n 2 >NUL 2>&1
    isKeyDown.exe a
    echo %errorlevel%
GOTO LOOP
```

and the batch script can correctly display the errorlevel the executable sets.  Also, if I put a character, say 'A,' in the executable directly, it will correctly determine when the key is pressed.  Since I've confirmed both of those it seems like something is wrong with '*argv[1],' and it's not precedence, since I checked.

*EDIT
As further response to the comments, the following code:

## include

## include

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
        std::cout << *argv[1];
    return (argc > 1 ? (GetKeyState(*argv[1]) & 0x8000) : 0);
}
```

will produce 'A0' in the console, so those weren't the issues, but they were good to try.  Thank you.

Comment: If you print the value of `argc` is it 2 as expected?  If you write `argv[0]` to the console, do you get something? Is it correct? Likewise with `argv[1]`.  If you step into the code with a debugger, does each variable correspond to expected values?

Comment: I'd have to remake the project as a console project to check that but I will when I get back from laundry. Thanks!

Comment: Please read [About Keyboard Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267.aspx) to understand virtual-key codes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so first I have to use
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

like so:

```
@ECHO OFF

:LOOP
    PING 127.0.0.1 -n 2 >NUL 2>&1 || PING ::1 -n 2 >NUL 2>&1
    isKeyDown.exe 11
    echo %errorlevel%
GOTO LOOP
```

then I can use

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int key;
    if (argc > 1)
        key = 16*(argv[1][0]-'0')+(argv[1][1]-'0');
    return (argc > 1 ? (GetKeyState(key) & 0x8000) !=0 ? 1 : 0 : 0);
}
```

which won't work for character inputs like $A3 yet but it's a big step!  I'll take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is just to allow someone to press a key to abort the script, consider [`choice`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_%28command%29) as an option.

```
@ECHO OFF

:LOOP
    PING 127.0.0.1 -n 2 >NUL 2>&1 || PING ::1 -n 2 >NUL 2>&1
    choice /C AB /T 10 /D B /M "Press A"
    if ERRORLEVEL 2 (
         echo "Timeout"
    ) else (
         echo "A"
         GOTO END
    )
GOTO LOOP
:END
```

This allows you to wait for input rather than having to hold down the key, and doesn't rely on an external application. (External in this case meaning 'not shipped with Windows') If there are other things being done by the executable, [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be the better option, since it grabs the current state of the key.

Comment: I wanted hotkeys actually, since the built in support is really buggy on my computer, but thank you for your response.